# Почему приложение на Flutter не получает данные с сервера? Подскажите, где ошибка

Tags: flutter, dart

Такая проблема: хочу разобраться, почему мое приложение во Flutter не получает данные с сервера с помощью библиотеки HTTP? Я использую API [Geography API][1]

[1]: https://apilayer.com/marketplace/geo-api?e=Sign%20In&l=Success&e=Sign%20In&l=Success# , чтобы получить информацию о стране: название (name), площадь(area), численность населения (population), язык(demonym) и регион (region). Ответ в JSON-формате должен получиться таким:

````
```
[
  {
    "alpha2code": "DE",
    "alpha3code": "DEU",
    "alt_spellings": [
      "DE",
      "Federal Republic of Germany",
      "Bundesrepublik Deutschland"
    ],
    "area": 357114.0,
    "borders": [
      "AUT",
      "BEL",
      "CZE",
      "DNK",
      "FRA",
      "LUX",
      "NLD",
      "POL",
      "CHE"
    ],
    "calling_codes": [
      "49"
    ],
    "capital": "Berlin",
    "currencies": [
      {
        "code": "EUR",
        "name": "Euro",
        "symbol": "\u20ac"
      }
    ],
    "demonym": "German",
    "flag": "http://assets.promptapi.com/flags/DE.svg",
    "gini": 28.3,
    "languages": [
      {
        "iso639_1": "de",
        "iso639_2": "deu",
        "name": "German",
        "native_name": "Deutsch"
      }
    ],
    "latitude": 51.0,
    "longitude": 9.0,
    "name": "Germany",
    "native_name": "Deutschland",
    "numeric_code": "276",
    "population": 81770900,
    "region": "Europe",
    "regional_blocs": [
      {
        "acronym": "EU",
        "name": "European Union"
      }
    ],
    "subregion": "Western Europe",
    "timezones": [
      "UTC+01:00"
    ],
    "top_level_domains": [
      ".de"
    ]
  }
]```
````

Но почему-то при этом вылезает ошибка ClientException. Помогите найти ошибку, сам все перепробовал, не нашел. Вот код моей модели:

````
```class CountryByName{
  final String name;
  final double area;
  final int population;
  final String demonym;
  final String region;

  CountryByName(
      {required this.name,
        required this.area,
        required this.population,
        required this.demonym,
        required this.region
      }
      );

  factory CountryByName.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json){
    return CountryByName(
      name: json['']['']['name'],
      area: json['']['']['area'],
      population: json['']['']['population'],
      demonym: json['']['']['demonym'],
      region: json['']['']['region']
    );
  }
}```
````

Это UseCase, который получает данные с сервера:

````
```class GetCountryByNameUseCase{
  Future<CountryByName> execute(String countryName) async {
    final url = 'https://api.apilayer.com/geo/country/name/$countryName';
    final apiKey = 'мой ключ';

    final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url), headers: <String, String>{
      'Authorization': 'Bearer $apiKey',
    });

    if(response.statusCode==200){
      return CountryByName.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load data');
    }
  }
}```
````

А это один из моих дочерних виджетов, где собственно и происходит запрос и вывод данных на экран:

````
```class CoutryInfoMainScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const CoutryInfoMainScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<CoutryInfoMainScreen> createState() => _CoutryInfoMainScreenState();
}

class _CoutryInfoMainScreenState extends State<CoutryInfoMainScreen> {
  var getCountryByNameUseCase=GetCountryByNameUseCase();
  late CountryByName countryByName;
  String name='';
  int population=0;
  double area=0.0;
  String demonym='';
  String region='';
  String error='';

  @override
  void initState(){
    getData();
    super.initState();
  }

  Future<void> getData() async{
    try {
      countryByName=await getCountryByNameUseCase.execute('Germany');
      setState(() {
        name=countryByName.name;
        area=countryByName.area;
        population=countryByName.population;
        demonym=countryByName.demonym;
        region=countryByName.region;
      });
    } catch (e) {
      setState(() {
        error=e.toString();
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Text('$name', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 40),),
        Text('City name', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30),),
        Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0),),
        Card(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  Text('Area:', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20)),
                  Text('$area', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20))
                ],
              ),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  Text('Population:', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20)),
                  Text('$population', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20))
                ],
              ),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  Text('Demonym:', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20)),
                  Text('$demonym', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20))
                ],
              ),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  Text('Region:', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20)),
                  Text('$region', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20))
                ],
              ),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  Text('Error:', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20)),
                  Text('$error', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20))
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}```
````